# Testing Content-Type in Response Header

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, reqwest

I'm trying to run an integration test for `Content-Type` in the response. It fails with error:

```
   --> tests\greet.rs:18:9
    |
5   |     let response = client
    |         -------- move occurs because `response` has type `Response`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
13  |         response.text().await.unwrap(),
    |                  ------ `response` moved due to this method call
...
18  |         response.content_length(),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `response`
   --> C:\Users\Saurabh Mishra\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\reqwest-0.11.12\src\async_impl\response.rs:146:23
    |
146 |     pub async fn text(self) -> crate::Result<String> {
    |                       ^^^^
```

And when I comment out the test for response body (`response.text()...`), all tests execute correctly.

The test suite is:

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn greeting_works() {
    spawn_app();
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let response = client
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello")
        .send()
        .await
        .expect("Failed to execute request");

    assert!(response.status().is_success(), "Endpoint validity");
    assert_eq!(
        response.text().await.unwrap(),
        "Hello, World!",
        "Response from endpoint"
    );
    assert_eq!(
        response.content_length(),
        Some(13),
        "Response length is 13 characters"
    );
    assert_eq!(
        response.headers().get("Content-Type").unwrap(),
        "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    );
}

fn spawn_app() {
    let server = mailrocket::run().expect("Failed to bind address");
    let _ = tokio::spawn(server);
}
```

How can I run this suite so that all four tests execute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` consumes the response, so you can no longer use it after you call the method.
A simple way to fix it would be to do the assertion on `.text()` last:

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn greeting_works() {
    spawn_app();
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let response = client
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello")
        .send()
        .await
        .expect("Failed to execute request");

    assert!(response.status().is_success(), "Endpoint validity");
    assert_eq!(
        response.content_length(),
        Some(13),
        "Response length is 13 characters"
    );
    assert_eq!(
        response.headers().get("Content-Type").unwrap(),
        "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    );
    assert_eq!(
        response.text().await.unwrap(),
        "Hello, World!",
        "Response from endpoint"
    );
}

fn spawn_app() {
    let server = mailrocket::run().expect("Failed to bind address");
    let _ = tokio::spawn(server);
}
```