# How to deal with "no method named `clone` found" for third-party struct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm a newbie at Rust and am trying use the value in `response` created in the code below twice:

```
    let response = reqwest::blocking::get(
    "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc&count=100"
    ).unwrap();
    r = response.clone(); // <- ERROR
    let response_text = response
    .text()
    .unwrap();
```

I get that if I assign `response` to `response_text` I lose access to it. So, I tried to clone it into another variable first. However, I get an error saying `` no method named `clone` found for struct `reqwest::blocking::Response` in the current scope `` .

How do I resolve this issue? Most results to a search of this problem suggest that I create my own struct, embed the `Response` struct in it and then manually implement a `.clone()` trait. Surely there's got to be a simpler way (I hope)!

Comment: Well if your proposed solution were possible you could just use that `Clone` implementation directly, without a wrapping struct, unfortunately it's not possible though. See also this Q/A about [tests on a `Response`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452379/testing-content-type-in-response-header/74452435#74452435)

Comment: This seems a little XY problem-y. `.text()` consumes the response, but most other methods on `Response` only take it by reference. If you called those before `.text()` there's no need to clone it to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @isaactfa, I agree with you and did manage to get it working by calling the functions in the "right" order. But I'm just trying to learn the language and am trying to figure out how not to forced into using this particular order. What if for some reason, I wanted to use the response object after calling the text method? It's obvious how to do it in most other languages and so I'm trying to figure out how I could do it in Rust.

Comment: @user3353185 that's not possible by design (of the library authors). The response for example might only stream the body and reading twice might not be possible or something similar.

Comment: "It's obvious how to do it in most other languages" yes because other languages either require you to track the allocation and deallocation of the memory associated with the response (C/C++) or have a garbage collector to perform this task for you (basically everything else). The tradeoff that you get for having the compiler perform this task for you (instead of doing it your self or paying the runtime tax) is that you **have** to care about the order of operations. You will have a much easier time if you stop trying to force Rust into familiar patterns and code with the grain of the language.

Comment: @user3353185 If you're trying to learn the language I think it'd be better to understand its semantics and not try to work around them at the first hurdle. You cannot clone a `Response` because it owns a stream that can be read only once. If you need to clone that data, you can get it out of the `Response` (e.g. using `.text()`) and clone that.

Comment: This isn't a "Rust" thing really, it's a choice made by the `reqwest` library authors. I'm sure there are very good reasons that `response.text()` consumes the response and also good (probably related) reasons why `response` does not implement `Clone`, but the most important reason for you is "the library authors designed it that way". Your choices are to use the library as the authors intend you to, or use another library that you prefer the style of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found most useful was from a comment by @isaactfa, which I reproduce verbatim here:

- You cannot clone a Response because it owns a stream that can be read only once. If you need to clone that data, you can get it out of the Response (e.g. using .text()) and clone that.*